# ERROR 1452. Al insertar registros mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una base de datos, pero necesito insertar los estados y municipios de México, hice mi diagrama EEER y de ahí genere mi base de datos, al hacer los insert de los estados no hay problema, ingreso 32 registros, pero al insertar los municipios, solo puedo insertar 32 municipios, al insertar el registro 33 me marca el error, el codigo de la creación de las tablas son las siguientes:

---

-- Table `CiInventario`.`estados`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CiInventario`.`estados` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clave` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `abrev` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `activo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `CiInventario`.`municipios`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CiInventario`.`municipios` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `estado_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `clave` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `activo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `estado_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `CiInventario`.`estados` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

la tabla de municipios tienen en Foreign Key Option "NO ACTION" en ON UPDATE y ON DELETE;

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (ciinventario.municipios, CONSTRAINT estado_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES estados (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: agrega todo el mensaje de error

Comment: Se me ocurre sin probar, que la inserción del municipio 33, le estás poniendo un estado que no existe, quizás el mismo número 33. Se supone que solo tienes 32 estados

Comment: Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ciinventario`.`municipios`, CONSTRAINT `estado_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `estados` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: las "id" de estados estan de la 1-32, sin interrupciones, los insert total de los primeros 5 estados son 32, por pura casualidad. El insert del estado con la "id" 6 es el registro 33, el cual ya no me lo admite, igual he intentado insertar datos con otros "id" de estados que existen pero ya no puedo insertar, es como si tuviera una restriccion en la tabla municipios de 32 registros igual que la tabla estados con la misma cantidad de registros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que tienes un error en la declaración de tu llave foránea que vinculará a tu tabla municipios con estados, justo aquí:

```
CONSTRAINT `estado_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `CiInventario`.`estados` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Por que estas apuntando a la misma columna `id` pero de la tabla `municipios`, cuando debería ser a la columna `estado_id` quedando de este modo:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_municipio_estado` FOREIGN KEY (`estado_id`) REFERENCES `CiInventario`.`estados` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Es decir:

- Tu función `foreign key` debe recibir el nombre de la columna que en la tabla municipios hará las veces de conector entre municipios y estados, que es `estado_id`
- El nombre de tu `CONSTRAINT` pudiera ser mejor una indicación del tipo que es y las tablas que vincula así: `fk_municipio_estado`

Comment: Asi es, no puedo creer que no me haya dado cuenta, muchas gracias!